# Как заполнить пустое поле CSS

Tags: css, центрирование

На картинке показано, что сайт оставляет пустое поле справа при уменьшении ширины окна. При этом в полный экран и при "определённой ширине до критического" - всё нормально (этого пустого поля нет). И чем сильнее сжимать, тем больше это поле. Как оно образуется... Пытался гуглить, но не смог подобрать даже слова. Везде попадаются статьи как заполнять поля внутри флекс-контейнеров. Мэрджины и педдинги - обнулял и ставил авто; ширину фиксировал, ставил 100% и авто! Не помогло...
Добавил в сниппет верстку. Сss код оказался слишком большой... пришлось сократить (убрать анимации и псевдосостояния), но проблема осталась...

[image: Показано свободное поле, которого не должно быть]

```css
html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Roboto-Medium", Roboto, "PT Sans Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #283136;

    background-color: #ffffff;
}

main{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.visually-hidden:not(:focus):not(:active),
input[type='checkbox'].visually-hidden,
input[type='radio'].visually-hidden{
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;

    white-space: nowrap;

    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
}

h3,h2,h1{
    color: black;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sliders{
    position: relative;
}
.slider{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;

    animation-name: slidersAnimation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
.sliders .button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 55px;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.slider-1{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.slider-2{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
.slider-3{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
.slider-indicators{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 50%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -65px;

    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.slider-indicator{
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
}
.slider-text{
    display: flex;
    order: -1;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 380px;
}
.slider-text h2{
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.slider-text p{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #283136;
}
.about-left{
    width: 660px;
}
.about-left h2{
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.about-right {
    width: 360px;
}
.about-left h3{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.about-right h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
.about-left p:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.about-right .item-right {
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*На кнопки*/
.button{
    transition-property: background-color, color, border;
    transition-duration: 150ms, 100ms, 50ms;

    font: inherit;

    cursor: pointer;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.button-red{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #fb565a;
}
.button-yellow{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #efc84a;
}
.button-green{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #00ca74;
}
.button-grey{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
/* Навигационное меню с самого верха*/
.main-header{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-color: #eeeeee;

    padding-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;;
}
.main-header h1{
    padding: 110px;

    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;

    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
}
.main-header-logo{
    align-items: baseline;
}

.main-navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    align-items: baseline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.site-navigation,
.user-navigation{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.user-navigation {
    margin-right: 55px;
}

.user-navigation .login-link{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 85px;
}
.login-link::before{
    content: "";

    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 45px;

    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;

    background-image: url("/img/ico/cart-icon.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    opacity: 0.45;
}
.site-navigation a,
.user-navigation a{
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 50px 20px 50px;
}


/*Раздел преимуществ*/
.feautures-list{
    list-style: none;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1100px;

    padding: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
.feautures-item{
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.feautures-item h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.feautures-item p{
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.feautures-item .button{
    padding: 15px 40px;
}
/*Модальное окно*/
.modal{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.modal button{
    padding: 18px 85px;
}
.modal legend{
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.modal-appointment {
    display: none;
    font: inherit;

    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px 1px black;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 85px 100px;

    position: fixed;
    top:120px;
    left: 120px;
}
.form-appointment-inputs{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    list-style: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.form-appointment-inputs li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 40px;

}
.form-appointment-inputs li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
.form-input-text textarea{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.modal-appointment input{
    min-width: 200px;
}
.modal-appointment input,
.modal-appointment textarea{
    font: inherit;
    color: #a1a1a1;

    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #d7dcde;
    outline: none;

    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.modal-appointment fieldset{
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.modal-appointment legend{
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;

    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.form-appointment-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 90px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: auto;
}
.form-appointment-close:hover,
.form-appointment-close:focus
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.form-appointment-close:active{
    opacity: 0.1;
}

.form-paragraph{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.orders-right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;
}

.about-logo{
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}
.about-logo img{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.about-logo img:active{
    transition: opacity 25ms linear;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.orders-logo{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: auto;

    border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;

    padding: 45px 65px 45px 40px;
    margin: auto;

    margin-bottom: 80px;

    list-style: none;
}

/**/
.main-footer{
    color: #000000;

    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.logo-social{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;
}
.logo-social-circle{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;

    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 12px;

    border-radius: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.logo-social-circle:hover,
.logo-social-circle:focus{
    transition: background-color 150ms ease-in;
    background-color: #e74246;
}
.logo-social-circle:active{
    transition: background-color, border 25ms ease-in;
    background-color: #d7373b;

    border-top: solid 3px #c13135;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo-social-circle img{
    padding: 30px;
}
.logo-social-circle img:active{
    opacity: 0.3;
}

/**/
.content{
    display: flex;
}
.content-sort{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    list-style: none;
}

.sort-content-items{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 360px;
    align-items: center;

    font-weight: bold;
}

.content-sort-item label{
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.content-sort-item input:checked + label{
    opacity: 1;
}
.content-sort-item:last-child label{
    margin-right: 0;
}
.content-sort-updown{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    list-style: none;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.pagination-list{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
}
.pagination-item{
    margin-right: 11px;

    border: 3px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.pagination-item-current{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.pagination-item:last-child a{
    padding: 15px 78px;
}


/*Columns*/

.studio-column{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    border-top: 2px #eeeeee solid;
    color: #283136;

    padding: auto;
    margin: auto;

    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 1160px;
}
.studio-column h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.orders-left{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.orders-item-left{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 35px;
}
.orders-item-left::before{
    content: "";

    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;

    background-color: #fb565a;
}

/*Logotipes*/

.contacts{
    position: relative;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.card{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.card img{
    min-height: 415px;
}
.modal-show-form{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 140px;

    padding: 50px;

    background-color: white;
}
.modal-show-form .button{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.footer-column{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.logo-right{
    margin-left: 140px;
}
.logo-right h3{
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color:black;
}

.sidebar-left{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width: 260px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #283136;
}
.sidebar .button{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
.sidebar fieldset{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    border: none;

    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.sidebar legend{

    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;

    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.sort-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
.sort-content h3{
    align-content: flex-end;
    margin-left: 140px;
}

.catalog{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 760px;

    margin-left: 140px;
}

.catalog-item{
    display: block;
    position: relative;

    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.catalog-item .button{
    display: block;

    padding: 15px 60px;
}

.price-hidden{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 30px;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 230px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #666666;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.price-hidden h3{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #000000;
}
.over-pic{
    opacity: 0.12;
}

.general-container{
    display: flex;
}
.main-column{
    display: flex;
}
.flex-price-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;

    width: 260px;

    color: #283136;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.price-quantity input{
    width: 80px;
    height: 38;

    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;

    margin-left: 13px;
}

.price-range input{
    width: 260px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.sidebar-input{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-input li{
    position: relative;

    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="8">-->
    <title>Дизайн-студия NERDS</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main-mini.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header class="main-header">
        <nav class="main-navigation">
            <a href="nerds.loc" class="main-header-logo">
                <img src="img/nerds-logo.svg" id="logotipe" width="160" alt="Логотип дизайн-студии NERDS">
            </a>

            <ul class="site-navigation">
                <li>
                    <a href="nerds-info.html">Студия</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="nerds-clients.html">Клиенты</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="nerds-catalog.html">Магазин</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="nerds-contacts.html">Контакты</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="user-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="login-link">
                    <!--<li class="trash-box">
                        <img src="/img/ico/cart-icon.png" id="trash-box-img" alt="Корзина">
                    </li>-->
                    <li class="trash-box">
                        Корзина
                    </li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section class="sliders">
            <!-- Радио-баттонс сделаю в диве пока -->
            <!-- А тут меняющиеся слайдеры, тоже пока на ДИВАХ -->
            <div class="slider slider-1">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="img/nerds-index-slide1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="slider-text">
                    <h2 class="slider-headline">Долго, дорого, Скрупулёзно</h2>
                    <p>Математически выверенный дизайн для вашего сайта или мобильного приложения</p>
                    <p><a class="sliders-button button-red button">Узнать больше</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider slider-2">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="img/nerds-index-slide2.png">
                </div>
                <div class="slider-text">
                    <h2 class="slider-headline">Любим математику как никто другой</h2>
                    <p>Никакого креатива, только математические формулы для расчета идеальных пропорций</p>
                    <p><a class="sliders-button button-red button">Узнать больше</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider slider-3">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="img/nerds-index-slide3.png">
                </div>
                <div class="slider-text">
                    <h2 class="slider-headline">Только ночь, только хардкор</h2>
                    <p>Работать днем, как все? Мы против этого. Ближе к полуночи работа только начинается</p>
                    <p><a class="sliders-button button-red button">Узнать больше</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="slider-indicators">
                <li>
                    <input class="slider-indicator" name="slider-indicator" type="radio" value="1" checked>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="slider-indicator" name="slider-indicator" type="radio" value="2">
                <li>
                <li>
                    <input class="slider-indicator" name="slider-indicator" type="radio" value="3">
                </li>
            </ul>

        </section>

    </header>

    <main class="container">
        <h1 type="hidden" class="visually-hidden">Мы — маленькая, но гордая дизайн-студия из Краснодара NERDS</h1>
        <h2 class="visually-hidden">Наши преимущества</h2>
        <section class="feautures">
            <ul class="feautures-list">
                <li class="feautures-item">
                    <img src="img/illustration-1.jpg" alt="Картинка изображающая веб-сайты">
                    <h3>Веб-сайты</h3>
                    <p>Мир никогда не будет прежним после того как увидит ваш сайт!</p>
                    <p><a class="button-red button">Заказать</a></p>
                </li>
                <li class="feautures-item">
                    <img src="img/illustration-2.jpg" alt="Картинка изображающая приложения">
                    <h3>Приложения</h3>
                    <p>Покорите топ-10 приложений в AppStore и Google Play</p>
                    <p><a class="button-green button">Заказать</a></p>
                </li>
                <li class="feautures-item">
                    <img src="img/illustration-3.jpg" alt="Картинка изображающая презентации">
                    <h3>Презентации</h3>
                    <p>Вы даже не подозреваете, насколько вы изумительны!</p>
                    <p><a class="button-yellow button">Заказать</a></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <div class="studio-column">
            <section class="about-left">
                <!-- Левый описание -->
                <h2>Мы — маленькая, но гордая дизайн-студия из Краснодара.</h2>
                <p>Исповедуем принципы минимализма и чистоты. Ставим математический расчёт выше креатива. Работаем не
                    покладая рук, как роботы.</p>
                <h3>Выполняем заказы на разработку: </h3>
                <ul class="orders-left">
                    <li class="orders-item-left">Веб-сайтов любой сложности</li>
                    <li class="orders-item-left">Моболиных приложений дл iOS и Android</li>
                    <li class="orders-item-left">Слайдшоу и видео для корпоративных презентаций</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="about-right">
                <!-- Правый описание -->
                <img src="img/nerds-illustration.jpg" alt="Логотип кампании NERDS">
                <h3>с 2004 года Любим точность во всем:</h3>
                <ul class="orders-right">
                    <li class="orders-item-right">
                        <span class="item-right">146 <sup>%</sup></span><br>
                        Уровень<br>
                        самоотдачи
                    </li>
                    <li class="orders-item-right">
                        <span class="item-right">100 <sup>%</sup></span><br>
                        Соблюдение<br>
                        сроков
                    </li>
                    <li class="orders-item-right">
                        <span class="item-right">50 <sup>%</sup></span><br>
                        Минимальная<br>
                        предоплата
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
        <section class="about-logo">
            <!-- Нижние логотипы под описаниями -->
            <ul class="orders-logo">
                <li class="orders-item-logo">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo-1.png" alt="Логотип HTML academy">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="orders-item-logo">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo-2.png" alt='Логотип барбершоп "Бородинский"'>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="orders-item-logo">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo-3.png" alt="Логотип Pink">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="orders-item-logo">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo-4.png" alt="Логотип Mishka">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>

    </main>

    <footer class="main-footer">

        <section class="contacts">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="img/map-marker.jpg" alt="Наше расположение на карте">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-show-form">
                <h2>NЁRDS DESIGN STUDIO</h2>
                <p>
                    191186, Санкт-Петербург, <br>
                    ул. Б. Конюшенная, д. 19/8
                </p>
                <p>тел. +7 (812) 275-75-75</p>
                <p><button class="button button-red" id="open-form">Напишите нам</button></p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--<img src="img/map-marker.jpg" alt="Карта, как проехать">-->
        <div class="footer-column">
            <section class="logo-social">
                <ul class="logo-social">
                    <!-- Картинки-ссылки для соц. сетей -->
                    <a class="logo-social-button" href="#">
                        <li class="logo-social-circle">
                            <img src="img/vk-icon.svg" alt="Логотип VK">
                        </li>
                    </a>

                    <a class="logo-social-button" href="#">
                        <li class="logo-social-circle">
                            <img src="img/fb-icon.svg" alt="Логотип Facebook">
                        </li>
                    </a>

                    <a class="logo-social-button" href="#">
                        <li class="logo-social-circle">
                            <img src="img/insta-icon.svg" alt="Логотип Insragramm">
                        </li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="logo-right">
                <h3 class="footer-right">Давайте дружить, это выгодно!</h3>
                <p><span class="footer-right-p">Скидка 10% для друзей из социальных сетей.</span></p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <section class="modal modal-appointment">

        <form class="form-appointment">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Напишите нам</legend>

                <img class="form-appointment-close" src="img/ico/close-cross-form.svg">
                <!--Кнопка закрытия-->

                <ul class="form-appointment-inputs">
                    <li class="form-input-item">
                        <label for="name">
                            <p class="form-paragraph">Ваше Имя Фамилия:</p>
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-text" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя Фамилия" required>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form-input-item">
                        <label for="email">
                            <p class="form-paragraph">Ваш e-mail:</p>
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-text" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="form-input-text">
                    <label>
                        <p class="form-paragraph">Текст письма</p>
                        <textarea class="form-textarea" name="text" id="text" required></textarea>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="button-submit button-red button">Отправить</button>
        </form>

    </section>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вместо скриншоты покажите вашу вёрстку, здесь отличный сниппет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту могу предположить что на определённой ширине установлен медиа-запрос, в котором задается ширина(вероятнее всего в %) для тега html или  для .main-header. Возможно это из-за класса mdl-js который находится в теге html, попробуйте его убрать. 
А вообще правильно вам ответили в комменте, что лучше закинуть сюда вёрстку

Answer (score 0):

В глобальном селекторе html{} задана ширина в %, а нижних блоках фиксированная ширина, поэтому браузер открывает фикс во всю ширину, а блок в % сужается по ширине браузера. Надо выбрать: либо полный фикс, либо адаптив. И главное: родительский элемент должен быть больше дочернего (вопрос очевидный)...